# F# Iterating Nested Dictionaries

Tags: recursion, dictionary, f#

I have an ugly debugging function for printing a 3 level map, in fact they're dictionaries. I've been trying to convert it so that I can print off an n-level map. This is my attempt so far:

```
open System.Text
open System.Collections.Generic

let rec PrintMap x = 
    let PrintVal (v: obj) = match v with
                            | :? seq<KeyValuePair<_,_>> as vm ->  "{ " + PrintMap vm + " }"
                            | _ -> sprintf "Value: %s" (v.ToString())
    let sb = StringBuilder()
    for KeyValue(key,value) in x do 
        sb.AppendLine(sprintf "%s => %s" (key.ToString()) (PrintVal value)) |> ignore
    sb.ToString()

type dict3 = Dictionary<string,obj>
type dict2 = Dictionary<string,dict3>
type dict1 = Dictionary<string,dict2>

let k1 = "k1"
let k2 = "k2"
let k3 = "k3"
let v  = "foo" :> obj

let dict = dict1()
dict.[k1] <- dict2()
dict.[k1].[k2] <- dict3()
dict.[k1].[k2].[k3] <- v

printf "%s" (PrintMap dict)
```

I'd rather not switch the nested dictionaries to their F# equivalents (at least for input) as the real thing deals with them.

You can probably deduce from what I'm almost certain is a naive attempt at an Active Pattern, not even mentioning the `StringBuilder`, that I'm quite new to F#. It seems my difficulty is telling the difference between a dictionary and 'everything else' when looking at the value, and informing the type inference system that the values aren't the same type as the dictionary in the 'x' parameter.

Any hints?

Thankyou!

#### Edit

A small elaboration --- sometimes I get just a `dict2` or `dict3` type instead of the full `dict1` so that's one of the reasons I'm trying to make this more generic.

### Solution

Thanks to Daniel:

```
let rec PrintMap x = 
    let PrintVal (v: obj) = match v with
                            | :? IDictionary as vd -> "{ " + PrintMap vd + " }"
                            | _ -> sprintf "%s" (v.ToString())
    let sb = StringBuilder()
    for key in x.Keys do 
        sb.AppendLine(sprintf "%s => %s" (key.ToString()) (PrintVal x.[key])) |> ignore
    sb.ToString()
```

The output is pretty ugly, but it certainly works. With the above input dictionary:

```
k1 => { k2 => { k3 => foo
 }
 }
```

Comment: As tempting as it may be, you shouldn't put your final solution in your question.  Best practice is to create a new answer with your final code in it (while still marking the appropriate answer as correct).

Comment: I have been meaning to give the FAQ a read over, sorry for the bad etiquette, I'll keep that in mind for next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `PrintVal`, the second case never matches because `seq<KeyValuePair<_,_>>` doesn't mean *any sequence of key value pairs regardless of type args*; it means *leave it to the compiler to infer the type args*. In other words, the underscores are only wildcards for the purpose of compile-time type inference, not pattern matching. In this case, the type args are likely inferred to be `<obj, obj>` which doesn't match any of the dictionaries in your test.

To pull this off, you'll likely have to match on a non-generic type, such as `System.Collections.IDictionary`.

Answer (score 0):

What I think you're trying to do will not work, and it's not so much about understanding F# here as understanding generics. You have to remember that both type inference and generics are *compile-time rules* so calling this function with objects whose types are determined at runtime will never work, because the compiler cannot determine which type parameters you want to apply. In other words, every time you call `PrintMap v`, the compiler must know the type of `v`.

In common with similar problems in C#, to solve this, you would have to go down the route of [dynamically invoking .NET methods using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/232535/how-to-use-reflection-to-call-generic-method).

Comment: Ok, I've tried to update the example so it looks more in line with F# idioms. The way I've updated it I think it should be quite close to working but I'm not entirely certain why the [type test](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dd547125.aspx) is always taking the second branch.

Answer (score 0):

While the solution suggested by [Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24243892/f-iterating-nested-dictionaries#24246425) works well with full-blown dictionaries, it cannot handle implementations of only `IDictionary<_,_>`, like those that are returned by the F# `dict` function. This can be achieved by testing for the interface and using non-generic `IEnumerable` to iterate its contents:

```
let getProp name x = 
    x.GetType().InvokeMember(
        name, BindingFlags.Public ||| BindingFlags.InvokeMethod |||
            BindingFlags.Instance ||| BindingFlags.GetProperty, null, x, null )

let rec PrintMap x = 
    match x.GetType().GetInterface "IDictionary`2" with
    | null -> sprintf "%A" x
    | _ ->
        let sb = StringBuilder()
        sb.Append "{ " |> ignore
        for o in unbox<System.Collections.IEnumerable> x do
            let (k, v) = getProp "Key" o, getProp "Value" o
            sb.AppendLine(sprintf "%s => %s" (string k) (PrintMap v)) |> ignore
        sb.Append " }" |> ignore
        string sb

dict["k1", dict["k2", dict["k3", "foo"]]]
|> PrintMap
```

The output (slightly different):

```
{ k1 => { k2 => { k3 => "foo"
 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I don't really think that reflection should be necessary, considering I'm fairly certain that this could be done in C# with nothing more than some strategic overloading.

Comment: @arfbtwn I don't think so. Daniel's point about the compiler being unable to infer any specific type for `KeyValuePair<_,_>` still applies, albeit you may be able to replace reflection with property access through C#'s `dynamic` feature.

Comment: just made a little attempt in C# without any reflection, I believe you are correct sir! - in that I was not successful :)